# How to send a string to my server using JSON? (tornado)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, tornado

So I have an HTML input box that calls a javascript function after clicking a submit button. I want to send the data the user enters in that input box to my tornado server. I'm very new to all of this, and have tried a few different options yet none have seemed to work. With this code, I get a 405 (method not allowed) error. Here is what I have right now:

```
var myData = hello

function pushURL(){

    var passThis = {
        apples : myData
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "/",
        type: 'POST',
        contenttype: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data : JSON.stringify(passThis),
        dataType: 'JSON'
    });
}
```

And here is my tornado script:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import json

#Utility libraries
import os.path

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('index.html')

#This tells tornado where to find static files
settings = dict(
    template_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
    static_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
    debug = True
)

# r"/" == root website address
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler)
],**settings)

#Start the server at port n
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('Server Running...')
    print('Press ctrl + c to close')
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I'm going to need to use the string in some server-side python scripts, but right now I'd just like to see it print to the console when the user clicks submit. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, if you can explain in somewhat ELI5 terms that'd be cool.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending data as post request from front-end to your index route, so you have to define a post method inside MainHandler class.
Please refer to this documentation [here](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/structure.html#handling-request-input).